# Context manager and daemon thread

Tags: python, multithreading, contextmanager

I am starting a daemon thread from a context manager that should send a heartbeat every second, but since it is running in a thread it will not terminate the context manager if an exception occurs. How do I raise an exception in the context manager when the heartbeats stops?

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep


@contextmanager
def plc():
    stop_event = Event()

    try:
        # Send heartbeat every second
        hb_t = Thread(target=heartbeat_task,
                      args=(stop_event,),
                      daemon=True)
        hb_t.start()

        yield
    except Exception:
        raise
    finally:
        stop_event.set()
        hb_t.join()
        print("Heartbeat stopped")


def heartbeat_task(stop_event):

    value = False
    
    while not stop_event.is_set():

        value = not value

        print("Heartbeat: " + str(value))

        sleep(1)


def main():

    with plc():

        while True:

            print("Program running")

            sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have a hard time finding examples of this.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Why do you need a context manager for this?

Comment: Actually I am not required to. I would like to do it in a procedural way and have the heartbeat abstracted away for simplicity. I want to make a simple library where the user of the library only needs to connect to the PLC and the heartbeat is started and stopped automatically (abstracted away).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I have modified the code to be more closely aligned with the code you posted. But:

Your code as presented has an inconsistency: `heartbeat_task` is passed an event that if set will cause the function to return. But it is only set when the context manager in function `main` created with `with plc():` exits, which is never. If you are hoping that any exception thrown by `heartbeat_task` will force the context manager to exit and then caught in function `plc`, then what is the point of it calling `stop_event.set()` if by definition we only arrive here if `heartbeat_task` is no longer running due to an exception?

So either you want `heartbeat_task` to run indefinitely until it raises an exception (in which case there is no point in having a "stop" event) or you want to be able to stop `heartbeat_task` when some condition exists, but there is no code for doing that. I will assume for demo purposes that `main` will be given access to the `stop_event` event and will set it under some circumstance. Otherwise, it runs until it detects that `heartbeat_task` is no longer running presumably because it raised an exception (it is executing an infinite loop, so how else could it terminate if the stop event has not been set?). What remains is why you need to be using a context manager at all. I will present an alternative later on.

If you use a multithreading pool (we only need one thread in the pool), it become simple for the main thread to catch exceptions thrown by a task submitted to the pool: When `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.apply_async` is called a [`multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) instance is returned that represents a future completion. When method `get` is called on this instance you either get the return value from the worker function (`heartbeat_task`) or any exception thrown by the worker function is re-raised. But we can also use method `wait` to wait for either the completion of the submitted task or an elapsed time. We can then test whether after waiting 5 seconds whether the submitted task actually finished (due to an exception or return) with method `ready`. If the task is still running, then we can tell it to stop. In this demo I force the task to raise an exception after approximately 7 seconds:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from threading import Event
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import sleep


@contextmanager
def plc():
    stop_event = Event()
    pool = ThreadPool(1)

    # Send heartbeat every second
    async_result = pool.apply_async(heartbeat_task, args=(stop_event,))
    yield stop_event, async_result
    # We only return here if the task is no longer running
    try:
        # See if task threw an exception and if so, catch it:
        async_result.get()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Got exception:", e)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print("Heartbeat stopped")


def heartbeat_task(stop_event):
    # For demo purposes, we will force an exception to occur
    # after approximately 7 seconds:
    value = False

    n = 0
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        value = not value
        print("Heartbeat: " + str(value))
        sleep(1)
        n += 1
        if n == 7:
            raise Exception('Oops!')


def main():
    with plc() as tpl:
        stop_event, async_result = tpl
        # This function could forcibly cause the heartbeat_task
        # to complete by calling stop_event.set()

        # Loop while the task is still running
        while not async_result.ready():
            """
            if some_condition:
                stop_event.set()
                break
            """
            print("Program running")
            # Sleep for 5 seconds or until heartbeat_task terminates:
            async_result.wait(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Program running
Heartbeat: True
Heartbeat: False
Heartbeat: True
Heartbeat: False
Heartbeat: True
Program running
Heartbeat: False
Heartbeat: True
Got exception: Oops!
Heartbeat stopped
```

**Alternative to Using a Context Manager**

```py
from threading import Event
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import sleep


def heartbeat_task(stop_event):
    value = False

    n = 0
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        value = not value
        print("Heartbeat: " + str(value))
        sleep(1)
        n += 1
        if n == 7:
            raise Exception('Oops!')

def main():
    stop_event = Event()
    pool = ThreadPool(1)
    async_result = pool.apply_async(heartbeat_task, args=(stop_event,))

    # Run as long as heartbeat_task is running:
    while not async_result.ready():
        """
        if some_condition:
            stop_event.set()
            break
        """
        print("Program running")
        # Sleep for 5 seconds or until heartbeat_task terminates:
        async_result.wait(5)

    # Any exception thrown in heartbeat_task will be rethrown and caught here:
    try:
        async_result.get()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Got exception:", e)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```